# Signal Handler running multiples times

Tags: c, ubuntu, signals

Currently writing a basic shell that handles signal interrupt with variety of other functions.

```
int numberOfCommands = 0;
int signalHandlerFired = 0;
char history[HISTORY_DEPTH][COMMAND_LENGTH];

void handle_SIGINT(){
            writeHistory();
            signalHandlerFired = 1;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char input_buffer[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    char *tokens[NUM_TOKENS];
    char cwd[COMMAND_LENGTH];
    struct sigaction handler;
    handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGINT;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &handler, NULL);

    while (true) {
        signalHandlerFired = 0;
        getcwd(cwd,  sizeof(cwd));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, cwd, strlen(cwd));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "> ", strlen("> "));

        _Bool in_background = false;        
        read_command(input_buffer, tokens, &in_background);
        if (signalHandlerFired == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        char exclamationCommand[2];
        exclamationCommand[0] = tokens[0][0];
        exclamationCommand[1] = '\0';
        char* hcNumber = &tokens[0][1];
        if (strcmp(&exclamationCommand[0], "!") == 0) {
            if (atoi(hcNumber) == 0) {
            } else {
                retrieveHistory(hcNumber, numberOfCommands, input_buffer, tokens, in_background);
            }
            continue;
        }
        insertHistory(&numberOfCommands, input_buffer, tokens);


        //exit
        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "exit") == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }

        //pwd
        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "pwd") == 0) {
            getcwd(cwd,  sizeof(cwd));
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, cwd, strlen(cwd));
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", strlen("\n"));
            continue;
        }       
        //cd
        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0) {

            int dcSuccess = chdir(tokens[1]);
            if (dcSuccess == -1) {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Invalid Directory", strlen("Invalid Directory"));
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", strlen("\n"));
            }
            continue;
        }
        //history
        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "history") == 0) {
            writeHistory(tokens[0]);
        }


        executeCommand(numberOfCommands, input_buffer, tokens, in_background);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the while loop in **main()** which gets inputs from the command line and does processing depending on the type of command entered, the signal handler will run twice or more depending on...is what I don't know.

The purpose of SIGINT [Ctrl+C] interrupt is to display the command history. This works fine if i run it once, but after..

```
/home/ahn/> ls
   Token: ls
a.out     Makefile.txt~   shell    shell.c~  shellsample.c~
Makefile  mystring_sol.c  shell.c  shell.o
/home/ahn/> ^C
History:
1    ls 
---------------Second Run
/home/ahn/> ks
   Token: ks
Unknown Command
/home/ahn/> ^C
History:
Number Of Commands: 2
1    ls 
2    ks 
/home/ahn/> 
History:
Number Of Commands: 2
1    ls 
2    ks 
/home/ahn/>
```

I think I don't have a clear understanding when interrupts happen, at which point in the program is returning too. Moreover, I have no idea why it is running twice. I will provide any function definitions if needed.

Also, the char ks comes out corrupted. Full core [here](http://pastebin.com/pp4uDdC3) if needed.

Comment: I looked through the full code and here's what I found. Handler's type is `void handler(int)` but not `void handler()` as you have it. Another thing is that your shell seems to spawns a new process on every unknown command, I'm pretty sure signal handlers plus file descriptors get inherited by those new processes so you get multiple history printouts from a number of processes on every single Ctrl+C hit.

Comment: Just in case you do: Do not `printf()` from signal handlers. `printf()` and certain other functions aren't necessarily async-signal save.

Comment: Also take care to **always** properly (re-)initialise all variables. This incudes but is not limited to "read"-buffers.

Comment: Also^2 this `buff[strlen(buff) - 1]` mostly is a way into desaster. Just imaging a `0`-length "string".

Comment: @IgorS.K. Thank you Genius, I had to add in a `exit(0)` in the child process condition to prevent running other code.